# How general is the backfitting algorithm?

Tags: nonparametric, consistency, efficiency, semiparametric

Hastie \& Tibshirani's original approach to fitting generalized additive models was the backfitting algorithm.  For a model of the form
$$
y = \alpha + \displaystyle\sum_k f_k(x_k) + \epsilon
$$

1. Initilize the $\alpha$ and $f_k$ at reasonable values
2. Loop through terms, subtracting off the current estimate of all others, in order to fit a bivariate model with a scatterplot smoother, like a local polynomial.  For the $m$th iteration:
   $$
   y - \alpha^m - \displaystyle\sum_{-k} f^m_{-k}(x_{-k}) \equiv y_k^m = f_k(x_k) + \epsilon
   $$
3. Do this until convergence.

This approach seems to have been superseded in most of applied statistics by penalized splines, of the sort implemented in `mgcv` in R, but is still used in [nonparametric econometrics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2681302/).

My question:  how general is the backfitting algorithm?  Are there restrictions on what smoothers one can use for the $f_k$?  For example, if a random forest were used ([shown recently to be consistent and asymptotically normal](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342)) in an additive model with high-dimensional additive terms, should one expect to consistently estimate the terms of the model?  Why or why not?

And even if such a model were consistent, what could be said about efficiency?